# Shiny: How to adjust the width of the tabsetPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

Here is my [app](http://analysisph.weebly.com/shiny-apps.html) embedded in my site. I want to get rid of the scroll widget below my app, this is due to the width of the tabsetPanel.

I embed the app using this code:

```
<iframe width="800" height="480" frameborder="0" src="http://spark.rstudio.com/alstated/meanvar/"></iframe>
```

App Codes:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(title = ""),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("size",
                "Number of Observations",
                min = 10,
                max = 200,
                value = 95),

    sliderInput("mu",
                "Mean",
                min = -100, 
                max = 100,
                value = 0),

    sliderInput("sd",
                "Standard Deviation",
                min = 1,
                max = 6,
                value = 3),

    checkboxInput(inputId = "indiv_obs",
                  label = "Show individual observations",
                  value = FALSE),

    checkboxInput(inputId = "density",
                  label = "Show density estimate",
                  value = FALSE),

    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.density == true",
                     sliderInput(inputId = "bw_adjust",
                                 label = "Bandwidth Adjustment",
                                 min = 0.2,
                                 max = 2,
                                 value = 1,
                                 step = 0.2))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", 
               plotOutput(
                 outputId = "histogram", 
                 height = "400px",
                 width = "400px")),
      tabPanel("Summary",
               verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "datsummary"))
    ))
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive(rnorm(
    n = input$size, 
    mean = input$mu, 
    sd = input$sd
  ))

  output$histogram <- renderPlot({

    hist(data(),
         probability = TRUE,
         xlab = "Data",
         ylab = "Density",
         main = "Histogram of Random Samples")

    if(input$indiv_obs){
      rug(data())
    }

    if(input$density){
      dens <- density(data(), adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    }

  })

  output$datsummary <- renderPrint(summary(data()))
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just tried it out, and I get a scrollbar on the right of the app, not below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figure it now, I inspect the html code of the app on Shiny [Homepage](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/). And the tabsetPanel is adjusted using the `<div>` (Document Division) tag in html by setting the option `class` to either `span1`, `span2`, `span3` and so on. The higher the suffix of the `span` the larger the width of the division. And I just add `div()` tag in my ui.R code:

```
div(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", 
                 plotOutput(
                   outputId = "histogram", 
                   height = "400px",
                   width = "400px")),
        tabPanel("Summary",
                 verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "datsummary"))
        ), class = "span7")
```

Comment: I found this answer quite helpful. I also wanted to point out the handy discussion over on google groups: http://goo.gl/L8vuOf

Comment: Can I just follow on that question and ask how to adjust *height*?

Comment: I realise that this answer was from long ago. I just tried it and it didn't work for me. @ChriiSchee's answer below worked well.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to adjust width (and height):

add

```
 ),  style='width: 1000px; height: 1000px' # end of tabsetPanel
```

after tabsetPanel, no need for div() in this case

Comment: this will transfer the style down to the next element inside which the tabsetpanel is placed I believe. In my case the tabsetpanel was inside a column with it's own style = 'width: 255px; etc' and resulted in a style error. When inspecting the element the column should warning: height:400px width:255px, without the needed ; to separate them, and clearly the height for the panel moves to the wrapping column. So you do need div

Answer (score 2):

The examples above work in certain circumstances. I needed a more general solution. The following solution can be tailored to any situation. For example, your Shiny app could still be responsive.

**My solution**

First, create a div before the tabsetPanel and give it a class. Second, write a piece of jQuery/javascript to find the parent element of that div. Third, change the class of this parent element using javascript/jQuery. You can change the class into anything you like, for example, col-sm-12, col-sm-11, some other standard Bootstrap class or you can add and create your own class. Fourth, add the custom jQuery/javascript to your Shiny application (make sure that you save the .js-file in the www folder of your Shiny app).

Here is my example:

**Javascript/jQuery (general.js):**

```
$(function (){
    $("div.delParentClass").parent().removeClass("col-sm-8").addClass("col-sm-12");

/* In addClass you can specify the class of the div that you want. In this example, 
I make use of a standard Bootstrap class to change the width of the tabset: col-sm-12. 
If you want the tabset to be smaller use: col-sm-11, col-sm-10, ... or add
and create your own class. */

});
```

**Shiny UI**

```
mainPanel(
    tags$head(tags$script(src="general.js")),
    div(class="delParentClass",
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Some panel", .....),
          tabPanel("Some panel", .....),
          tabPanel("Some panel", .....)
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A different way to adjust the width of `sidebarPanel` and `tabsetPanel` was based on modifying the `width` property of the `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-8` CSS classes, respectively.
Using `tag$head` and `tag$style` it is possibile to add CSS directly to the Shiny UI.
See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html for details.
This is not an elegant solution, but it works correctly.

**Shiny UI**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("   
     .col-sm-4 { width: 25%;}
     .col-sm-8 { width: 75%;}
    "))
  ),       
  headerPanel(title = ""),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("size",
                "Number of Observations",
                min = 10,
                max = 200,
                value = 95),

    sliderInput("mu",
                "Mean",
                min = -100, 
                max = 100,
                value = 0),

    sliderInput("sd",
                "Standard Deviation",
                min = 1,
                max = 6,
                value = 3),

    checkboxInput(inputId = "indiv_obs",
                  label = "Show individual observations",
                  value = FALSE),

    checkboxInput(inputId = "density",
                  label = "Show density estimate",
                  value = FALSE),

    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.density == true",
                     sliderInput(inputId = "bw_adjust",
                                 label = "Bandwidth Adjustment",
                                 min = 0.2,
                                 max = 2,
                                 value = 1,
                                 step = 0.2))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", 
               plotOutput(
                 outputId = "histogram", 
                 height = "400px",
                 width = "400px")),
      tabPanel("Summary",
               verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "datsummary"))
    ))
)
)
```