# Shiny: How to increase the width of tabsetPanel to cover the whole area to the right of the sidebarPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a shiny app in which there is a sidebarPanel and tabesetPanel.

I created the app using the code below

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
h1("Shiny app"), 
tags$hr(),
h2("several options here"), 
width =2),
mainPanel(uiOutput("tb"))
)
)
server <- function(input,output){
output$diamonds1 <- renderPlot({
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, col=clarity)) + 
                     geom_point(alpha=0.5)+ facet_wrap(~color, scales="free")
})
output$diamonds2 <- renderPlot({
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, col=clarity)) + 
                     geom_point(alpha=0.5)+ facet_wrap(~cut, scales="free")
})
output$info <- renderPrint({
nearPoints(diamonds, input$plot_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
           addDist = TRUE)
})    
output$tb <- renderUI({
tabsetPanel(tabPanel("First plot", 
                     plotOutput("diamonds1")),
            tabPanel("Second plot", 
                     plotOutput("diamonds2", click = "plot_click"), 
                     verbatimTextOutput("info")))      
})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want the tabsetPanel to cover the whole area to the right of the sidebarPanel.

As suggested in [the answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096439/shiny-how-to-adjust-the-width-of-the-tabsetpanel), I tried the following

```
div(, class ="span12")
```

and

```
),  style='width: 1000px;)
```

However, still the tabset panel and the plots don't cover the whole area to right of the sidebarPanel.

Any suggestions how to do that?

**Update**

Thanks to @K. Rohde's answer, the plot now covers the whole height of the page next to the sidebarPanel but still doesn't cover the whole width

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Sorry for not checking my first answer. But here is something that works:

For some reason, `plotOutput` is broken in the sense that `height = "100%"` does not work, otherwise that would be a solution. But you can add css3 by hand which scales your plot according to window size with `...vh`.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("Shiny app"), 
      tags$hr(),
      h2("several options here"), 
      width =2),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input,output, session){
  output$diamonds1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, col=clarity)) + 
      geom_point(alpha=0.5)+ facet_wrap(~color, scales="free")
  })
  output$diamonds2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, col=clarity)) + 
      geom_point(alpha=0.5)+ facet_wrap(~cut, scales="free")
  })
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(diamonds, input$plot_click, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
               addDist = TRUE)
  })    
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("First plot", 
                         tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#diamonds1 {height:95vh !important;}")),
                         plotOutput("diamonds1")),
                tabPanel("Second plot", 
                         tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#diamonds2 {height:80vh !important;}")),
                         plotOutput("diamonds2", click = "plot_click"), 
                         verbatimTextOutput("info")))      
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I admit, it's more of a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Still, the tabset panel and the plots don't cover the whole area to right of the sidebarPanel.

Comment: Many thanks for your timr and help. You fixed the height of the plot but still the plot width and tabset panel don't cover the whole area to the right of the sidebar panel. Please, check the result in this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/fquv5qtscfd3edq/1.png?dl=0

Comment: @aelwan Have you tried `mainPanel(width = 10, ...)`?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is exactly as I wanted.