# R Shiny: center tabsetPanel labels

Tags: css, r, shiny

How can I center the labels that are visible in the tabsetPanel? Currently I define the tabs using renderUI:

```
output$uiTabs <- renderUI({
tabsetPanel(tabPanel("visualization1",tableOutput("table1")),
            tabPanel("visualization2",tableOutput("table2"))) })
```

Then in UI I have something like this:

```
    column(8,align="center",
           uiOutput("uiTabs"))
```

Now the tables are center aligned, but not the tabs themselves.

Comment: Is it possible to create empty/unclickable tabPanels? So perhaps

`tabsetPanel(

tabPanel(tags$div(
                                     HTML(paste(tags$span(style="color:white", "TYPE A LONG STRING HERE TO SPACE ACCORDINGLY"), sep = ""))
                                   )),
tabPanel("visualization1",tableOutput("table1")),
tabPanel("visualization2",tableOutput("table2")),
selected = "visualization1"

)`

Has the appearance of an empty tab, and the only issue is that that the you're able to select the "empty" tab with white-space being its label.

Comment: Thank you, that worked nicely. I tried a similar approach earlier, but it looked bad because I didn't change the style using HTML unlike you.

Comment: I posted the above as an answer. Perhaps check mark it until someone provides something better? Please keep me informed: this is definitely something I'm interested in as well.

Comment: Yep this is good enough for now, but we'll see if someone has a bit more elegant solution! :D I'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what we talked about in the comment section of the OP

```
#tabsetPanel holds all of the tabs

tabsetPanel( 

#create an empty tab with white text being the label
#Inserting more text will increase the width of the label

            tabPanel(tags$div( 

              HTML(paste(tags$span(style="color:white", "TYPE A LONG STRING HERE TO SPACE ACCORDINGLY"), sep = "")) 

             )), 

#Other tabpanels

            tabPanel("visualization1",tableOutput("table1")), 

            tabPanel("visualization2",tableOutput("table2")), 

#Make sure to keep the selected = "tabPanel id" here because 
#it will default select the empty panel 

selected = "visualization1")
```

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that the tabs are only centered for a specific window size. When for example switching from a monitor with a different resolution the tabs are not centered anymore.

Comment: is there a way you can take a certain % of window space? For example in `dygraphs`, there are plot options to display width = 80%. Are there options to take a certain % of window space?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096439/shiny-how-to-adjust-the-width-of-the-tabsetpanel?rq=1

Comment: Instead of assigning pixel widths, it would be a percentage size. I've used similar stuff in an app of my own. Only issue is that you have to use this for the label: I'm not sure how to do that. http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/mainPanel.html