# Set tabPanel all on 1 row in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am having trouble fixing the tabs on the `tabPanel` I created to get them all on one row. Ignore the black box, it happened when I was trying to edit the picture. [image]

When I expand the page, they all fit. So I do think fixing a width would solve the issue. Or by removing the surrounding white space. There doesn't seem to by anything out there that I could find that solves this issue, so I haven't tried much.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme='stylepage.css',
    # Application title
    titlePanel(title=div(img(src='My_Logo.png',width='500px',height='200px'), align='center')),
    mainPanel(
        # Output: Tabset w/ headers ---
        tabsetPanel(type = 'tabs',
                    tabPanel('Section 1'), 
                    tabPanel('Section and Other 2'),
                    tabPanel('Section 3'),
                    tabPanel('Section and Other 4'),
                    tabPanel('Section and Other 5'),
    )
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to wrapping your `tabsetPanel` in `mainPanel`; try removing the surrounding `mainPanel` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861026/tabsetpanel-not-filling-whole-page-in-shiny) for an example).

Alternatively, you can increase the width argument in `mainPanel`. See [`?mainPanel`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/mainPanel.html).